# Why my recursive function is giving me an error output?

Tags: python, recursion

I am currently doing the edX course on Computer Science and on the one of  the recursion exercises I am stuck with the problem. I have checked the code on 'paper' several times but couldn't see what's wrong with it.

The problem in summary is stated as following:
Using the bisection search method find out if the char in isIn(char, aStr) function is present in the string (aStr)

Here is the code that I wrote:

```py
def isIn(char,aStr):

    aStrSorted = sorted(aStr)

    if len(aStrSorted)==0:
        print('The string you have given to me is empty')

    if len(aStrSorted)==1:
        print('The character you are looking for is in the ' + str(aStrSorted))

    if char == aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2]:
        print('The character you are looking for is in the string ' + str(aStrSorted))

    elif char<aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2]:
        return isIn(char,aStrSorted[0:len(aStrSorted)//2])
    elif char>aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2]:
        return isIn(char, aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2:-1])
    else:
        print('The character you are looking for is not in the string ' + str(aStrSorted))


isIn('f', 'abcdegghkl')
```

The error message is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
The string you have given to me is empty
  File "C:/Users/abkk1l/PycharmProjects/edX/edX-2.py", line 29, in <module>
    isIn('f', 'abcdegghkl')
  File "C:/Users/abkk1l/PycharmProjects/edX/edX-2.py", line 22, in isIn
    return isIn(char,aStrSorted[0:len(aStrSorted)//2])
  File "C:/Users/abkk1l/PycharmProjects/edX/edX-2.py", line 24, in isIn
    return isIn(char, aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2:-1])
  File "C:/Users/abkk1l/PycharmProjects/edX/edX-2.py", line 24, in isIn
    return isIn(char, aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2:-1])
  File "C:/Users/abkk1l/PycharmProjects/edX/edX-2.py", line 18, in isIn
    if char == aStrSorted[len(aStrSorted) // 2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It returned "The character you are looking for is in the middle of['a']" twice for me without any error

Comment: In which editor you have run the code?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Did you make a variable called `str`? If this is the REPL, try `del str`.

Comment: Why is are all your lines shown as `<input>`? How do you run this code?

Comment: Sorry guys, I was executing it form console and the str was somewhere above in the lines. It is hard moving from Matlab to python, when you had a pleasure of 'clear all'

Comment: However, after correcting it my code is working fine when there is a char in string, but fails when it is missing. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Given that `isIn()` is a predicate function name (should return either `True` or `False`), and sorting the string (and needlessly, all the sorted string's substrings) seems overkill, I'm going to guess that you've misunderstood the problem and suggest a simpler solution like:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):

    length = len(aStr)

    if length == 0:
        return False

    if length == 1:
        return aStr[0] == char

    halfway = length // 2

    return isIn(char, aStr[:halfway]) or isIn(char, aStr[halfway:])


if isIn('f', 'abcdefghkl'):
    print('The character you are looking for is in the string')
else:
    print('The character you are looking for is not in the string')
```

Comment: So if looking at my code and ignoring the uselessness of sorting substrings, the problem is that my function is not returning the true or false?

Comment: @KamranAbbasov, that isn't the problem with the code you wrote, it's a design issue with the code you should have written.